# Icarus verilog syntax error in a generate block

Tags: verilog, development-tools

In the top level of a module, I have the following block:

```
   genvar i;
   generate 
      for (i = 0; i < DEPTH; i++) begin
       fifo_element #(WIDTH) element (.clk(clk), 
                       .d_in(e_qd[i]), 
                       .d_in_strobe(e_in_strobe[i]), 
                       .q(e_qd[i+1]),
                       .q_ready(e_qready[i]), 
                       .in_strobe_chain(e_in_strobe[i+1]), 
                       .q_out_strobe(e_out_strobe[i+1]), 
                       .out_strobe_chain(e_out_strobe[i]),
                       .prev_used(i == 0 ? 1'b0 : e_used [i-1]), 
                       .next_used(i == DEPTH-1 ? 1'b1 : e_used [i+1]), 
                       .used(e_used[i]));
    end // for (i = 0; i < DEPTH; i++)
   endgenerate
```

When I attempt to compile this with icarus verilog (v10.1, using the `-g2009` command line option) I get the following errors:

```
fifo.v:84: syntax error
fifo.v:96: error: invalid module item.
fifo.v:97: syntax error
```

These errors correspond to the line containing `for`, the last line of the `element` instantiation, and the line containing the `end` that corresponds to the `begin` of the `for` block.  If I delete the apparently-unnecessary `begin` and `end` markers the third error goes away but the other two remain.

What's wrong with my code?  Or is this a problem with Icarus Verilog?  (A little research suggests that while earlier versions didn't support `generate` blocks at all, they've been supported for some time now, so what I'm trying to do here *should* work)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe you need i = i +1 instead of i++. Other than that, I don't see anything obviously wrong.

Comment: This is it.  Apparently the `++` operator is only supported in procedural code (i.e. testbenches) and not in anything that is part of synthesis.

Comment: @Jules: It is most likely that your synthesis tool does not support the ++ operator.

Comment: @toolic - it definitely does, in other contexts, which is what confused me ... I've used it extensively in testbench code without any error.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that you need to explicitly enable verilog 2001 features. I don't know what icarus is, but all the commercial tools I've used require a switch to enable v2k or 2001 or whatever the tool calls it.

Comment: That's the `-g` command line option: I've tried `-g2001`, `-g2005`, and `-g2009`, all of which should support it.  AIUI, the 2005 variant is the default.